# SQL Server Transaction Log Huge

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transaction-log

I came to work today and I saw the transaction log with 441GB, using almost all disk space.
I use SQL Server 2012 and have Full backup, but somehow I lost control of the t-log.
So, I need to do 2 things: first, clear the log, so I have the disk space back and control it.
I thought to control it doing daily backups. But I just can't figure how to reduce it.
Shriking is not a good thing to do, and anyway will take AGES to do it. I've try to bakcup the log like this: Backup Log DB_1 TO DISK = 'Nul:' but nothing changed.
So what exatcly can I do to fix this situation?

Thank you!

Comment: Why on earth would you try backing up to `NUL`? If you don't care about transaction log backups (and point-in-time recovery), stop using full recovery. If you do care, then start backing up your log properly (not to `NUL`).

Comment: I care about transaction log, but I have to reset then I will control it's size. It became a monster so I have to start over or at least reduce it size.
I'm backuping to nul so it truncate. But the size did not changed.

Comment: And even I don't care with a point-in-time recovery and change it to simple, the log still with 411GB. Need to clear it up!

Comment: Truncate <> shrink. Truncate is just freeing up space within the file. Switch to simple recovery mode, issue `CHECKPOINT;` twice, then use `DBCC SHRINKFILE`.

Comment: USE DB_1;
    GO
    CHECKPOINT;
    GO
    CHECKPOINT;
    GO
    DBCC SHRINKFILE(Demo_Log, 200);
    GO

Nothing changed.

Comment: What does `SELECT recovery_model_desc, log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'demo';` say?

Comment: Nevermind. Changed to simple, shrinked and back to full, now controling the file. Thank you!